# Memtest86+ Result Decoding

Tags: hardware, memory

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (fresh install with all updates)
Nvidia 8400GS Galaxy (instead of the on-board video)
Dell

I'm having random freezes where everything locks up, no mouse/keyboard/etc. Upon running Memtest86+, I get a "Unexpected Interrupt - Halting" error.  I disconnected everything except for the keyboard/mouse/monitor/added video card when I ran the test.

I've searched *everywhere* for what this means, but I only seem to find where people have the same error, but with a CPU0 at the end (e.g., "Unexpected Interrupt - Halting CPU0").

Does anyone have any idea what the error message means when there's just the "Unexpected Interrupt - Halting" error?

I'm starting to test the memory modules one-by-one, but it would be nice to know if there's potentially something else going on.

Learning a lot and really enjoying the OS (when the computer doesn't crash :-) ).

Comment: From the source code of the memtest86 program it looks like the next line contains the type of interrupt. What does the "Type" line say?

Answer (score 0):

From the source to memtest86+ I can see that the version (4.20-1.1ubuntu1) in Precise handles parity errors explicitly. (PARITY_MEM is defined in config.h to enable separate handling of vector ==2).

So the error you are getting is not for a memory parity error.

As a guess I would suggest that the memory test is triggering some memory-mapped I/O in your system, causing an interrupt as an accidental byproduct. This doesn't necessarily suggest a problem.

Knowing the kind of interrupt from the next line of the error screen might help someone to narrow this down.